# Qual é a melhor forma de salvar arquivos, Banco ou File System?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou com uma demanda de anexar PDFs à minha aplicação. Os arquivos tem tamanhos variados, de 5 a 200 MB ou mais.

Aqui vem a minha dúvida: qual a melhor opção armazenar?

- Direto no banco de dados (PostgreSQL)
- No sistema de arquivos

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens?

Comment: Não sei se essa pergunta pode ou não ser respondida objetivamente, mas de todo modo achei uma boa pergunta! Se você puder elaborar um pouquinho mais o que você entende por "melhor opção" (mais rápido? que gasta menos espaço? mais fácil de dar manutenção? etc), creio que terá mais chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Comment: No mesmo banco da sua aplicação começar a armazenar arquivos que podem chegar a 200MB, eu não faria isso. Talvez em um banco separado.

Comment: Uma desvantagem de salvar no disco é quando possuir um serviço de alto tráfego que exige mirrors. Então teria que fazer mirror também desses arquivos em disco. Caso estejam em banco de dados é mais simples solucionar por meio de replication. Na prática dá na mesma, mas a diferença é o trabalho na implementação.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pergunta parece ser off-topic, por ser muito ampla e até mesmo baseada em opiniões pessoais, não há algo "exato". Mesmo assim vou compartilhar uma experiência que tive, além citar algumas coisas quanto as abordagens.

Quanto à sua pergunta em específico, vamos primeiro falar quanto a persistir no PostgreSQL, vantagens e desvantagens segundo eles [próprios](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB):

- vantagens:

  - segurança e controle de acesso são simplificados;
  - controle de versão é fácil;
  - ACID
  - backups são simples
- desvantagens:

  - performance: é dependente do desempenho do seu filesystem;
  - maior necessidade de memória para processamento;
  - backups serão maiores, claro;
  - acesso pela sua aplicação será maior. Clientes de acesso a banco normalmente geram arquivos temporários para acessar e modificar os arquivos. (já pensou fazer isso para um arquivo de 200MB? o_O)

E quanto a usar file system normal (solução from scratch):

- vantagens:

  - rápido acesso e menos overhead, mas altamente dependente da infra;
  - mais fácil de manipular que algum SGBD;
  - não perde em performance a medida que cresce (considere criar algo que não persista tantos arquivos no mesmo diretório, por exemplo)
- desvantagens:

  - se preocupar com backups, espelhamento;
  - sem suporte transacional, pode gerar lixo, você terá que controlar isto;
  - em uma solução caseira pode ter problema em acessos simultâneos;
  - se preocupar com questões de segurança (local de armazenamento dos arquivos, quem pode ou não acessar, etc.);
  - se preocupar em não armazenar muitos arquivos;
  - tendem a ficar fragmentados, acesso mais lento;

Isto aí acima é sempre considerando que a infra é sua, ou seja, que é você que controla tudo, pois alguns dos problemas são tratados se você usa alguma coisa na nuvem, como memória e tudo o mais. Numa solução caseira para armazenar em file system você tem que se preocupar com muita coisa, não vejo por que dispender tempo nisto hoje em dia. A [referência](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB) na wiki do PostgreSQL é muito boa, considere ler e ver as outras referências por lá =)

Agora, a experiência pessoal que inclusive pode resolver problemas citados antes: caso você possa optar por isto, seu ambiente dê suporte a consumir serviços de terceiro, opte por serviços como [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) e [Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/). No meu caso, uso S3 para arquivos mais recentes e os movo para o Glacier depois de uma certa "idade", por questão de custo mesmo. Neste caso, eu tenho persistido em base apenas o local em que os arquivos estão salvos, muito performático e não me preocupo com backups, etc.

Existem outros serviços no mercado, como o [Google Blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/) e [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/) do Google e na Azure o [Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/storage/blobs/).

Esta abordagem irá resolver problemas citados antes, como a segurança de acesso, backups, escalabilidade, etc, além do que deixa você se concentrar no seu problema, não precisa reinventar a roda.

Caso em seu ambiente não seja possível adotar coisas assim, considere adotar um GED da vida para facilitar sua vida.

Talvez interesse:

- [Database System vs File System](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/storage/blobs/)

Answer (score 1):

Não existe uma resposta correta para sua pergunta, existem muitas coisas a se levar em conta, como por exemplo :

1. a quantidade de arquivos a ser gerados
2. frequencia de uso
3. segurança
4. outros...

Porém, eu faria da seguinte forma:

1. Arquivos salvos em diretórios
2. Localização dos arquivos salvo no banco

Dicas:
Utilize algum algoritmo de criptografia para gerar nomes aleatorios de diretorios, dificultando para que os usuarios tenham acesso à outros arquivos.
Além disto, não esqueça de setar corretamente as permissões de acesso à estes diretórios.